# Stochastic integral with respect to local martingale

Tags: reference-request, book-recommendation

Hey I need to define stochastic integral with respect to a local martingale. Can anyone recommend me some books in which I could find all needed information?

Answer (score 1):

Brownian Motion and Stochastic Calculus by Ioannis Karatzas and Steven Shreve.